# Django rest framework views organization using generics

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Taking my first steps in django here, building a simple crud api where i have two entities: device and property.

my project `urls.py` looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from devices.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('devices.urls')),
]
```

and my app `urls.py` as follows:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('device/create/', views.DeviceCreate.as_view()),
    path('device/update/<int:pk>/', views.DeviceUpdate.as_view()),
    path('device/delete/<int:pk>/', views.DeviceDelete.as_view()),
    path('device/', views.DeviceList.as_view()),
    path('device/<int:pk>/', views.DeviceDetail.as_view()),

    path('property/create/', views.PropertyCreate.as_view()),
    path('property/update/<int:pk>/', views.PropertyUpdate.as_view()),
    path('property/delete/<int:pk>/', views.PropertyDelete.as_view()),
    path('property/', views.PropertyList.as_view()),
    path('property/<int:pk>/', views.PropertyDetail.as_view()),
]
```

which is somewhat repetitive but ok, the real problem is my views file is far more repetitive:

```
from rest_framework import generics

from .models import Device, Property
from .serializers import DeviceSerializer, PropertySerializer

from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

class DeviceCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Device.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer

class DeviceList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Device.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer

class DeviceUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Device.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer

class DeviceDelete(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Device.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer

class DeviceDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Device.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer

class PropertyCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Property.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PropertySerializer

class PropertyList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Property.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PropertySerializer

class PropertyUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Property.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PropertySerializer

class PropertyDelete(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Property.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PropertySerializer

class PropertyDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Property.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PropertySerializer
```

i looked over the web for example's and it does seem like a valid way (plus my app is working) but is there a way to improve my `views.py` file to get the same result with less code?

Comment: You should consider executing the tutorial from start to end.You would have found ViewSets which would help make your code more compact.

Comment: so the tutorial didn't include viewSets but it does have a link to a farther tutorial about this topic, which i'll definitely use now ,thanks

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/ part of the tutorial ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one `ModelViewSet` for your `PropertySerializer` and one for your `DeviceSerializer`

The ModelViewSet provides default `create`, `retrieve`, `update`, `partial_update`, `destroy`, and `list` actions.

Your `views` wil look like this:

```
class DeviceViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Device.objects.all()


class PropertyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PropertySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Property.objects.all()
```

You wil then register your views with a router in your `urls.py` as follow:

```
from . import views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'devices', views.DeviceViewSet, base_name='device')
router.register(r'properties', views.PropertyViewSet, base_name='property')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Note that your serializer class would then also have to be a `ModelSerializer`:

```
class DeviceSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('foo', 'bar')


class PropertySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('foo', 'bar')
```

You can read more about this in the [rest framework docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [ModelViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) from rest_framework in such case, f.e. for devices it would be one ViewSet as shown below:

```
class DeviceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Device.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer
```

then in your urls.py

```
from myapp.views import DeviceViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'device', DeviceViewSet, base_name='device')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

---

The main difference is that you have the same endpoint for different operations. They are distinguished by HTTP methods, f.e.

- GET `/devices` would be equal to your `DeviceList`
- GET `/devices/<id>` would be equal to your `DeviceDetail`
- POST `/devices` would be equal to your `DeviceCreate`
- PUT `/devices/<id>` would be equal to your `DeviceUpdate`
- DELETE `/devices/<id>` would be equal to your `DeviceDelete`